# Как правильно добавить Header в ListView?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить размер отмеченных красным цветом, чтобы при отображении присвоить их Headerу который отмечен зеленым цветом?

Надо чтобы Header тоесть текст зеленные блоки были с такой же шириной что и красные. Как в таблице Excel или SQL.

Comment: Ну задайте им в разметке одинаковую ширину и будет вам счастье. Не `wrap_content` же для столбцов использовать.

Comment: @xkor, а как узнать сколько нужно указать? ведь на разных телефонах по разному будет отображаться

Comment: Столько, сколько нужно для отображения нужного вам контента в адекватном размере. Ширина у телефонов не на столько уж и разная. Минимум 320dp, у большинства 360dp, более менее адекватный максимум 480dp. Так же можете задавать не жесткий размер а выставлять колонкам веса через атрибут `layout_weight`.

Comment: я вчера Вам пример писал, не успели прочитать? Просто создайте любую разметку, укажите параметры соотношения Веса layout_weight, выровнять по центру, проставить одинаковые отступы и тд. жаль что правильные ответы удаляют(((

Comment: @xkor, а разве правильно ли указывать размеры цифрами?, говорят это плохой код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подытожу комментарии:

Вам не нужно получать размеры красных блоков и задавать их программно зеленым блокам. Вам нужно в разметке (xml) задать одинаковые размеры (ширину) для красных и зеленых блоков. Либо через доли (веса в LinearLayout), либо непосредственно в `dp`.

По поводу правильности указания размеров цифрами... Я не знаю где вы слышали такую глупость, что это плохо, хотя возможно вы вырвали это утверждение из контекста в котором оно имело смысл. Плохо указывать размер цифрами там где по логике размер должен зависеть от контента. Плохо НЕ указывать размер цифрами там где он НЕ должен зависеть от контента. Ширину столбцов же указывать следует либо в долях (весах), либо в фиксированных цифрах, возможно разных для нескольких опорных размеров экрана. На моём текущем проекте например есть таблица с результатами гонок, там используется две разметки: портретная и ландшафтная. И 4 варианта размеров (dimensions) столбцов: телефон в портретной ориентации, телефон в ландшафте, планшеты с небольшим экраном (7-9") и планшеты с большим экраном (планшеты только в ландшафте). Этого вполне хватает для нормального внешнего вида на всех устройствах.